# passing more arguments to glob function in perl

Tags: perl, glob

```
push @hex_locations, glob("$ptxdist_env->{root}/project/platform-$PLATFORM-$BUILD_SUBTYPE/build-target/gnss-*");
push @hex_locations, glob("$ptxdist_env->{root}/project/platform-$PLATFORM-$BUILD_SUBTYPE/build-target/gps-q6image-*");
push @hex_locations, glob("$ptxdist_env->{root}/project/platform-$PLATFORM-$BUILD_SUBTYPE/build-target/hexagon-infra-*");
push @hex_locations, glob("$ptxdist_env->{root}/project/platform-$PLATFORM-$BUILD_SUBTYPE/build-target/tfcs-*");
```

is there a better way to do this, like giving it in one single line instead of 4? I had to use glob as it has wildcard at the end, when I try to use it in single line, the glob complains about too many argument.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are four:

1. ```
   my @hex_locations = (
       glob("$base/gnss-*"),
       glob("$base/gps-q6image-*"),
       glob("$base/hexagon-infra-*"),
       glob("$base/tfcs-*"),
   );
   ```
2. ```
   my @hex_locations = glob(join(' ',
       "$base/gnss-*",
       "$base/gps-q6image-*",
       "$base/hexagon-infra-*",
       "$base/tfcs-*",
   ));
   ```
3. ```
   my @hex_locations = map glob("$base/$_-*"),
      qw( gnss gps-q6image hexagon-infra tfcs );
   ```
4. ```
   my @hex_locations = glob("$base/{gnss,gps-q6image,hexagon-infra,tfcs}-*");
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
my @loc = ("gnss-*","gps-q6image-*","hexagon-infra-*","tfcs-*");

for (@loc) {
    push @hex_locations, glob("$ptxdist_env->{root}/project/platform-$PLATFORM-$BUILD_SUBTYPE/build-target/$_");
}
```